# Jenkins Plugin Google Play Upload Android APK to Google Play fail: nullpointerexception

Tags: android, jenkins, google-play, jenkins-plugins

The Jenkin PlayStore upload plugin seems not working for me, always get the following weird error. Manually upload the jenkin apk builds works just fine. Any idea or guess why?

The following is the Jenkins output console, and thanks so much in advance.

```
Archiving artifacts
Authenticating to Google Play API...
- Credential:     xxxxxxx
- Application ID: com.xxx.xxx

ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googleplayandroidpublisher.Util.getPublisherErrorMessage(Util.java:97)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googleplayandroidpublisher.ApkPublisher.publishApk(ApkPublisher.java:383)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googleplayandroidpublisher.ApkPublisher.perform(ApkPublisher.java:198)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1749)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
Build step 'Upload Android APK to Google Play' marked build as failure
```

Comment: hi, @Sean did you resolved the issue. I am facing the same issue. If yes, can you please help me there.

Comment: I don't remember the exact fix, either one of the following: 1) remove and re-install Jenkins, or perhaps I did the dirty fix by sudo and chmod a lot directories.  My problem was related to the Jenkin installation/upgrade permission, somehow Jenkins process did not have enough file permissions for certain folders.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/google-play-android-publisher-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/googleplayandroidpublisher/Util.java) it appears that a PublisherApiException is being thrown with no error messages.

This is super strange, because looking at [the source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/google-play-android-publisher-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/googleplayandroidpublisher/PublisherApiException.java#L14) this list should always be populated.

So I can't see any way this could happen with the current source. You might want to try updating your plugin, or running it in a debugger (or adding print statements) to see what is going on.

Comment: Looking at the source code of the exception the messages list can be empty in case of an authentication failure. For me this was the cause of the error. After fixing the permissions in the Google Play console it worked fine.